# Chinese string in the text of a label

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a label where I have to put a string in Chinese extracted from a database, but nothing comes out. I noticed that the string is not pulled from database, while all other work correctly. What can I do?

```
  char *subTitle= (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,13);
  NSLog(@" The sutitle is %s", subTitle);
      //The sutitle is
  rowTable.sottotitolo = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String: subTitle];
  NSLog(@"The subtitle is %@", rowTable.sottotitolo);
      //The subtitle is
```

Using methods other than Western alphabet?

```
   NSLog(@"The string in chinese is %@", self.chinaTable.subtitle);
         //The string in chinese is 
         //is not printed to the screen,but the database is written correctly

   self.labelTitle.text = self.chinaTable.subtitle;
        //empty out
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe You need to use a font capable of showing that chinese char?

Comment: you can get help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115359/how-to-read-chinese-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you retrieving your data from sqlite, instead of specifying the encoding schema, use this:

```
NSString *myChineseText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, index)];

NSLog(@"%@",myChineseText);
```

Hope, it'll solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding` and `kCFStringEncodingBig5_E`.

Also see [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html) and for [international](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i)
or for creating own encoding [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053197/ios-stringwithcontentsofurl-with-encoding)
 and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH2g-BCIHAEFA)

```
unichar ellipsis = 0x2026;
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To be continued%C", ellipsis];

// custom encoding

NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseTrad);

NSData *asciiData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:encoding 
                            allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData 
                                              encoding:encoding];
```